# Save to a variable the number of times the user answered "no" in java

Tags: java

good afternoon, I'm studying java, happened to get an assignment to make the following questions:

1. give input to the scanner "do you want to close this application? "
2. If the answer is "no", the input will appear again with the same question.
3. If the answer is "yes" the input does not appear again.
4. Save to a variable the number of times the user answered "no"

I want to make a count when the user answers NO it will count.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LatihanWhile6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputClose = "TIDAK";
        int jumlah = 0;
        while (inputClose.equals("TIDAK")) {
            System.out.println("Apakah anda ingin menutup aplikasi ini ?");
            Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputClose = inputKeyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }
        System.out.println("User yang menjawab TIDAK adalah : " + jumlah);
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you need to print the 'how many user answer no?' or you just need how to store the value?

Comment: I think that you need to read about [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com).

Comment: I suggest that you put the following line of code **before** the `while` loop: `Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: I need many users answered no...

Comment: There are some other things that you are doing incorrectly.  One is that you are not actually **counting** the number of times that the user said No (or "TIDAK").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, you just need to save the result on 'the number of times the user answered "no"'. I suggest you to use while loop and a variable to store the value

```
...
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputClose = "TIDAK";
        int jumlah = 0;
        while (inputClose.equals("TIDAK")) {
            System.out.println("Apakah anda ingin menutup aplikasi ini ?");
            Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputClose = inputKeyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            
            // add 'jumlah' value if input is still "TIDAK" after the scanner get the input value
            if (inputClose.equals("TIDAK")) jumlah++
        }

        System.out.println("User yang menjawab TIDAK adalah : " + jumlah);
    } 
...
```

but I suggest you to use more user friendly input detection if you getting the input from keyboard typing. Use the `equalsIgnoreCase` to able to take any other string `"TIDAK"` format. Here is the example

```
...
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputClose = "TIDAK";
        int jumlah = 0;
        while (inputClose.equalsIgnoreCase("TIDAK")) {
            System.out.println("Apakah anda ingin menutup aplikasi ini ?");
            Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            // no need to reformat to uppercase
            inputClose = inputKeyboard.nextLine();
            
            // add 'jumlah' value if input is still "TIDAK" after the scanner get the input value
            if (inputClose.equalsIgnoreCase("TIDAK")) jumlah++
        }

        System.out.println("User yang menjawab TIDAK adalah : " + jumlah);
    } 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to increment your counting variable `jumlah` each time you go threw the loop. When useing a while loop the variable should start add -1 because the loop will have one more run for the yes case. That said I have a little tip for you: close your inputStream when you done using it for good style with a call of the `close` function

```
        String inputClose = "TIDAK";
        int jumlah = -1;
        Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (inputClose.equals("TIDAK")) {
            System.out.println("Apakah anda ingin menutup aplikasi ini ?");
            inputClose = inputKeyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            jumlah++;
        }
        System.out.println("User yang menjawab TIDAK adalah : " + jumlah);
        inputKeyboard.close();
    }
```

Comment: ok i will try it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int yesNumber = 0;
        String inputKeyboard = "yes";

        while (!inputKeyboard.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.print("Do you want to continue(yes/no) ? ");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            inputKeyboard = reader.readLine();
            if(inputKeyboard.equalsIgnoreCase( "no"))
                break;
            else if (inputKeyboard.equalsIgnoreCase( "yes"))
                yesNumber++;
            else {
                System.out.println("Please answer with only yes or no !!!");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Number of yes : " + yesNumber);
    }
```

Comment: ok i will try it, thank you